# Как убрать градиент при наведении мыши в tailwind?

Tags: tailwindcss

В примере ниже класс hover:bg-none не убирает градиент (bg-120  from-medium-blue to-light-blue), как это можно исправить?

```
<button class="focus:outline-none font-Raleway w-37.5 h-12.5 rounded-full uppercase font-semibold my-2.5 cursor-pointer  bg-120  from-medium-blue to-light-blue hover:bg-none text-text-dark transition duration-300 ease-in-out border-2 hover:border-text-dark border-white">Далее</button>
```